# MYSQL: Why SELECT [explicit column names] is faster than SELECT *

Tags: mysql, select

I've experienced this first hand but I'm having a hard time locating any resources on the subject after several Google searches:

```
SELECT * FROM Table LIMIT x
```

has a slower return time than explicitly listing *all of a specific table's column* names:

```
SELECT id, name, email, address, phone, sex, date, ip FROM Table LIMIT x
```

What is the reason for this?

(assuming you are Explicitly Selecting *all* the column names, i.e., the table contains only columns id, name, email, address, phone, sex, date, ip)

Comment: It has to do more work—you have to look up the column names first. But honestly, this should be a constant difference for the table and thus you shouldn't worry too much about it. (Of course, you should list only the things you actually *need*.)

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether you're trying the two statements in order, at around the same time. Most database systems will cache data, and so the second statement could benefit from data still being available in memory due to the first statement.

Comment: Do you list all table columns is second case or only those you need?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: not in MySQL. Query cache in MySQL is using hash of query as a key.

Comment: Looking up column names shouldn't take any noticeable time, what Damien mentioned is the most probably the cause of time difference.

Comment: What is the magnitude of the difference in time, and how does that compare with the total time? How big is the data set - how many rows in Table and how big is each row? Are you getting all columns? What is the size of `x` in the LIMIT clause? Local or remote access? What else is going on at the same time? How many times did you run the queries to get the timing? Did you run them in the other order and compare times then? Did you check the explain output to see if there was anything different about the way the queries are processed? The difference between the two should be almost unmeasurable.

Comment: @Mchl: Damien is probably referring to a data cache, not an SQL statement or query plan cache.  Doesn't MySQL have a data cache, so that if two queries are reading the same table at the same time, each can benefit from the work done by/for the other?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: yes, it does of course. I realize now this might have been what Damien was referring to.

Comment: TO CLARIFY: 

 Explicitly Selecting ALL of the columns by name is in fact FASTER than using the simpler *

 Why? This seems like it wouldn't be an issue but I've done the edits in my code to explicitly list every column name in a table rather than the * and it's definitely a faster query and reduces MySQL's load... WHY?

Comment: Sorry for making so many additional comments - Re: Jonathan Leffler, the magnitude of Difference? I've run on Media Temple (gs) and as they only allow 80 Database connections at any given time, By changing the SELECT * over to explicitly select ALL column names from a specific table, it reduced the databsae server load and allowed faster database connect/disconnects for the 80 allowed DB connections and thus allowed the site to operate under the same load WITHOUT crashing for the 81st connector.

Comment: IT MAKES TOTAL SENSE that explicitly stating the names of each and every column in a table will return the same result in the same amount of time as SELECT * but this is NOT the case in MySQL for some reason. WHY?

Comment: RE: elevener; I listed all of the table columns.

Comment: RE: nobody, you're right, it SHOULDNT take longer to select all of the explicitly listed column names versus * but it does, and THAT's my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `select *` the rdbms has to expand the `*` to the column names and do the select after words.  When you provide explicit column names that step isnt necessary.

Comment: But when you list the names, the DBMS has to check that they are all valid, so it does essentially the same work as if you type '`*`'.

Comment: Sure, Exactly, However it seems that MySQL has a larger hit than your typical RDBMS does to expand the * to include all the column names. WHY is this inefficient with MySQL vs other RDBMS'es ?

Comment: Re: Jonathan Leffler, I agree, that makes sense, but for some reason when I read somewhere online that it's faster to explicitly list column names (reason for post: can't find that resource now) -- I changed my queries to select [explicitly, all, column, names, instead, of, *] from table, I noticed a dramatic improvement in the quickness of a database connection -- the server was able to handle a greater load with the same number of connections to the database, [i.e., each database connection completed faster] and THAT is my question.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence 'using SELECT with explicitly listed columns is faster than SELECT *' has sense when you in fact list only some of the columns in table. For example, if you only need an ID from table containing several long VARCHAR or TEXT fields, grabbing only one column will save a lot of time and bandwidth.

Comment: THIS is exactly why I've posted this problem. Because MySQL in fact returns the query faster without the * and the explicit column names, irregardless (I know you hate that word :) of whether or not you are in fact reducing the number of columns.

Comment: In other words, YES, the query would be much faster if you ONLY fetch the columns that you want, but the FACT IS MySQL will return the results FASTER with *all* of the explicit column names VS just the * -- iamkrillin's answer is the obvious one but my question is WHY is querying all of the explicit column names faster THAN the more simpler "select *" with mysql.